# Grunt option without the variable name

Tags: gruntjs, arguments, command-line-interface

I'd like to use grunt for deployment and type `grunt deploy production` instead of `grunt deploy --target=production`. As I don't have more parameters, I would like an option to just get the first parameter into a variable. Is it possible?

Comment: You can register a new task called **grunt deployProduction**, like this **grunt.registerTask('deployProduction')** and execute the tasks for production

Comment: Yes, that's something like I have now, but I would like it to be more dynamic so I could add other stages effortlessly.

Comment: Enviroment variables? type process.env.node_enviroment?

Answer (score 2):

In many of my Grunt configurations I use https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config. Then deploying to production is this:

```
NODE_ENV=production grunt deploy
```

The `deploy` task is generic, for instance regarding the target folder. The production configuration is available from a dedicated file, for instance `production.json`, and would hold that folder name.